# Changing Theme colors items in themes.xml dosn't change anything in the app

Tags: android, xml, themes

I want to customize my App Theme . i changed `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` and other attributes but non of them made any changes in the app.

Manifest.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.miplan">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage">

</uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LogoActivity"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

themes.XML :

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MiPlan" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">#458077</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#620051</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FD1CC1</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#FFFF</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#FF25</item>
        
    </style>
    

</resources>
```

Comment: Change `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">` to use your theme `Theme.MiPlan`. You've created a theme but are not using it for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your created theme by this

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MiPlan"
```